# Error using jChartFX with SharePoint 2013

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, jchartfx

I am attempting to create a graph in a web part using jChartFX.  However, when I include the jchartfx.system.js file, the Visual Studio debugger breaks on a JavaScript runtime error, stating that a semicolon (;) is expected.  The file in question is inplview.js, a SharePoint file.  If I remove the jchart.system.js file, everything is kosher.  Is jChartFX simply not compatible with SharePoint, or am I doing something wrong?  If it's incompatible, are there similar libraries that I can use to create a graph?

Answer (score -1):

Add the following basic references in the same order.

```
jquery-1.10.2.min,
jchartfx,
jchartfx.system,
jchartfx.coreBasic,
jchartfX.coreVector,
jchartfx.advanced,
jchartfx.coreVector3d
```

If you are trying to view the chart in IE 9+ then add the following in the meta tag

```
content=IE=9
```

Regards,
Thenga Thotti Nadana Kulu